# Reason for blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php 
class Customer extends CI_controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Customer_model');


}
public function create()
{

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');  
    $this->load->view('master/customer');

    }
    else
    {
    $this->Customer_model->register();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('templates/success');
    }
    }
}
```

I have inserted data successfully to the table using this code. After I have tried to display the same header template and the center part (success.php) it is showing a blank page. After commenting the header page it is working I.E. The success page is coming.

Comment: Then post your header page code also. You might have displayed some defined values.

Comment: Your header page probably has a syntax error. Whatever the problem is, the answer is in the server error logs.

Comment: Are you using FastCGI for running PHP scripts?

Comment: "Reason for blank page" - is that a cue for a song?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `load` the `helper` also above it:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```